# preventing a default function on top of another js event within the same element

Tags: jquery

I have a div, I want the div to to go to a link when clicked on. However, within the div, I also have a link that I simply want it to add a product to cart (via ajax), but NOT go to the link.

PARENT ELEMENT JS FOR LINK

```
$(document).on("click", '.product_result', function(){
url = $('h3 a',this).attr('href');
window.location = url;
});
```

CHILD ELEMENT FOR ADD TO CART

```
$('.product_add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pid = $(this).siblings('.product_pid').val();
    var quantity = $(this).siblings('.product_cart input').val();
    var product_name = $(this).siblings('.product_name_add').val();
    add_cart(pid,quantity);
    cart_status(quantity,product_name); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="product_result_wrapper">
    <div class="product_result">
        <div class="result_image"><img height="100" width="150" alt="Product NAme" src="image.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="product_info">
            <h3><a href="link" title="image">Product Name</a></h3>
            <p class="product_info_desc">CONTENT</p>
            <div class="product_price"><span>Price:</span>&pound;495.00</div>
            <div class="product_more_info"><a href="link">More Info</a></div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="product_order">
            <div class="product_cart">
                <input type="text" value="1"/>
                <input class="product_pid" type="hidden" value="44"/>
                <input class="product_name_add" type="hidden" value="product_id"/>
                <input class="product_add" type="button" value="Add to Cart"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the issue is the .product_add element, within the .product_result element. I hacked it by creating an extra parent element, .product_result_wrapper, and placed the add_cart element in there (not shown in this code) and simply changed the position of the element to appear within the .product_result element.

I also tried it with CSS, making it a higher z-index, with relative positions, but this did not work either.

So how do I prevent the default of a js event? So that I can include a different element withe the same event within this element, but to do a different action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `e.preventDefault();` in the `$('.product_add').click(function(e){})` function to `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

That must prevent the .product-result click listener from being triggered

Comment: Do you know why it can be messy? Or any downsides?

Comment: It can get messy when you have more listeners doing the stop propagation thing, because then you need to play with the order they are triggered in, more elements get involved etc. But if you just keep it to one level this is an ok solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for `e.stopPropagation()`, not `e.preventDefault()`.  It is, however, always messy to use either one of these.  The cleanest fix, if possible, would be to be more specific on what should trigger the 'parent element link', e.g. instead of

```
$(document).on("click", '.product_result', function(){
    ...
```

something like

```
$(document).on("click", '.product_result h3 a', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    ...
```

Again, I don't know if this is possible for you, but here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/byre1vpn/) you can play around with.

Comment: Ok, I think it that case I will just hyperlink the image, title and description, that sounds like the easiest solution here. Thanks